# Map.clear() then add map to List

Tags: java, apache-poi

I try to traverse some excel2007 data by using poi.jar based on **jdk1.6**.But when I seem to find a strange phenomenon that when I traverse the row(stored by *HashMap*()) and then add the row data to java.util.**ArrayList**  .

And starting the next iterator,I first clear the row data by invoking Map.clear(), but when again invoking the ArrayList.add() method,this row data is overridden the older data.

```
   Map<String, String> cellForRow = = new HashMap<String, String>();
   List<Map<String, String>> rowForSheet = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
   for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); j++) {

                    row = sheet.getRow(j);
                    if (j == 0) {// the first row is title
                        titleRow = row;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (row != null && titleRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells() > 0) {
                        // cellForRow = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        cellForRow.clear();
                        for (int k = 0; k < titleRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); k++) {// cell
                            cellForRow.put(getCellValue(titleRow.getCell(k)), getCellValue(row.getCell(k)));
                        }
                    }
                    rowForSheet.add(cellForRow);
                }
```

Next Snippets show the debug log for **rowForSheet**(List)

```
[{ Up =Stream, Email=XXX,Down =Stream},
{ Up =Stream, Email=XXX,Down =Stream},
{ Up =Stream, Email=XXX,Down =Stream},
{ Up =Stream, Email=XXX,Down =Stream},
{ Up =Stream, Email=XXX,Down =Stream}]
```

the later data override the older data

Did you?

Comment: Why would you add the same map to your list multiple times?

Comment: Did you what? Please end your sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would put the creation of your map inside of the loops so you add a *new* map each time.

```
List<Map<String, String>> rowForSheet = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); j++) {

   row = sheet.getRow(j);
   if (j == 0) {// the first row is title
      titleRow = row;
      continue;
   }
   Map<String, String> cellForRow = = new HashMap<String, String>();
   if (row != null && titleRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells() > 0) {
       for (int k = 0; k < titleRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); k++) {// cell
           cellForRow.put(
               getCellValue(titleRow.getCell(k)), 
               getCellValue(row.getCell(k))
           );
       }
   }
   rowForSheet.add(cellForRow);
}
```

Now each item in the list will be a different map, with the new data you've added.

Comment: I know this way could solve the problem.But I think this way is wasteful.If the row data is billion level ,then would waste the memory.

Comment: Why would you put the same map in the list more than once? Your way is broken. Why is this way wasteful?

Comment: Because I think every loops create a new hashMap,and then these maps are free.So...(Maybe it's only my thought.).Would you have a better way to replace it .Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Andy.wang you have a list, and you are putting 1 hashmap in it multiple times. If you modify that hashmap, the changes will show at every position in the list. You literally want a new hashmap at each position. First you should learn java, then you should learn how to make it more efficient.

Comment: you are right.Indeed I should strength my java basic.